# Track database history

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlite

```
def startlog():
    id = enteruser.id
    x = time.localtime()
    sec = x.tm_sec
    min = x.tm_min 
    hour = x.tm_hour + 1
    day = x.tm_mday
    date = f"{x.tm_mon}-{x.tm_mday}-{x.tm_year}"
    starttime = (day * 86400) + (hour * 3600) + (min * 60) + sec
    updatestart = "UPDATE log SET start = ?, date = ? WHERE ID = ?"
    c.execute(updatestart, (starttime, date, id,))
    conn.commit()
```

I have this function startlog, and a clone of it endlog.

My database log is consisted of (name, starttime, endtime, date)

Is there any way to keep track of the changes?

Desired output:

Name / Time / Date

x / time1 / date1

x / time2 / date2

I tried creating a list so everytime I'm calling out the function it will append on the list but it disappears after the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used csv for my case since it's just a personal project. I used columns like ID/Time in / Time out / Total Time and used ID to determine which value to display. This is the snippet of my code (using tkinter for gui)

```
def csvwrite():
    with open ('test.cvs', 'a', newline="") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        tup1 = (enteruser.id, log.start, log.end) 
        writer.writerow(tup1)
        csvfile.close()
        
def csvread():
    with open('test.cvs', 'r') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            filtered = filter(filterer, reader)
            res = []
            for i in filtered:
                print(i)
                historylbl = Label(historyWindow.historywndw, text = i)
                historylbl.pack()
```